# passing parameters to php in a form?

Tags: php, forms

I have the basic html form echoed through php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["pk"]))
 { $pk = $_GET["pk"];}
echo '<form action="up.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to pass the value of pk to up.php

Modifying action="up.php?pk=$pk" did not work.

Comment: Caution!!! DO NOT print out unformatted values (e.g. echo $_GET['pk']) to a page! It is a security hole which introduces a world of issues (XSS just to name one).

If "pk" is the primary key of a database and it is a number, you can either sanitize with a regex or with the intval() function

Comment: I won't be printing it out to a page, it will be passed to up.php where it will be inserted into a database via a parametrized query Why is there a need to sanitize it in transit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pk" value="<?php echo $pk; ?>">
```

By the way, printing large amounts of HTML like you have there is *ugly*. Consider either stepping out of PHP to do so, using HEREDOC, a template engine, or a framework.

**EDIT**:

As noted below, you should not print GET and POST data back to the page without sanitizing it first. Assuming pk is a primary key, you should wrap `$pk` above with the [intval](http://www.php.net/intval) function, *at the very least*.

Comment: Upvoted this, but see my note attached to the question about printing values from GET/POST data.

Comment: Sigh. Yeah, yeah, I know. I can only say it so many times in answers here until I stop caring. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with all the comments regarding some kind of input control of the $_GET['pk'] variable. I would recommend the filter module in php, which is pretty much a default installed module I believe.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
 $param = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pk', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
?>
<form action="up.php<?php echo (isset($param) && $param != false) ? '?pk=' . $params : ''); ?>" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find more information about the filter module here: [link text](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

I also agree with Paolo Bergantino, this is not the prettiest way to do it, and a template engine, heredocs or regexp could be a better way of increasing the readability and maintainability of the system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a variable inside a single-quoted string:

```
$pk = 123;
echo 'Hello $pk'; // echos Hello $pk
echo "Hello $pk"; // echos Hello 123
echo 'Hello ' . $pk; // echos Hello 123
```

The best way to pass it through would be as a hidden field inside the form

Answer (score 0):

Try sth like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$params = "";
if (isset($_GET["pk"]))
  { $params = "?pk=" . $_GET["pk"];}
echo '<form action="up.php' . $params . '" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you should be aware that $_GET["pk"] may contain pretty much anything, so think about some kind of input sanitization.